# Why a storyboard contain a UITabBarController can't present another storyboard/

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

The code about present another independent storyboard as follows:

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *secondStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *firstVC = [secondStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"22"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:firstVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If my storyboard like follow contain a `UITabBarController` the Pesentbutton with function           `-(IBAction)action:(id)sender;` can't present another independent storyboard.

[image]

If my storyboard like follow contain a `UINavigationController` the Pesentbutton with function         `-(IBAction)action:(id)sender;` presents another independent storyboard as expected.

[image]

Who can tell me the reason?More thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first case `self.navigationController` is nil... Since no navigation controller is present. Try presenting from `self` or `self.tabBarController`